# Elasticsearch 6 on AWS: EC2 discovery plugin not able to discover other nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I wasn't able to setup a Elasticsearch (v6.2.3) cluster on AWS, I installed the EC2 Discovery Plugin and configure it but none of the nodes are able to discover each other.

Here my config:

```
network.host: _ec2:privateIpv4_,localhost
plugin.mandatory: discovery-ec2
discovery:
    zen.hosts_provider: ec2
    ec2.groups: sg-xxxxxxxxx
    ec2.host_type: private_ip
    ec2.availability_zones: eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b
```

Answer (score 0):

After activating the ec2 plugin logs 
`logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2: "TRACE"`

it turns out there's a missing parameter you need to define `ec2.endpoint`

Final configs looks like this:

```
network.host: _ec2:privateIpv4_,localhost
plugin.mandatory: discovery-ec2
discovery:
    zen.hosts_provider: ec2
    ec2.groups: sg-xxxxxxxxx
    ec2.host_type: private_ip
    ec2.endpoint: ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
    ec2.availability_zones: eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b
```

There's a PR to make a default ec2.endpoint and update the docs accordingly.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/30323/